# Will my customized version of 11.10 be broken when I update to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, gnome, 12.04

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 for my mother on her computer. I did some little tweaks to make it easier for her:

- installed gnome shell
- installed some gnome extensions (but no shell frippery things...)
- uninstalled/installed some programs like rhythmbox, sound juicer etc.

Since the 11.10 version of Ubuntu is no LTS, I was wondering if her system will be fine after an upgrade to 12.04 LTS, or if it will be broken.
Of course, since 12.04 hasnt been released yet, you cant really tell, but mabye you have experiences from previous version upgrades.
What do you think - will gnome-shell be affected at all? It is hard to access her computer, so a seamless upgrade would be very nice...

Answer (score 3):

Don't think it's going to break, especially given the fact that the version of Gnome3 in 12.04 will remain the same, 3.2.

That said, I wouldn't recommend telling your mother to upgrade on her own. Plan in advance, and do it yourself, so that if something does break, you can take care of it. Read the release notes before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you installed and removed things from the repositories, everything should be fine. It's when you install things from source that they are likely to break on upgrades.